# Cycle decomposition in Python

Tags: python

Is there an algorithmically better way of doing this?

```
import numpy as np
l=np.random.permutation(10)
p=list(range(10))
print(l,p)
i=0
k=0
prod=1
z=0
def gcd(a, b):

    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
def lcm(a, b):

    return a * b // gcd(a, b)

while z<10:
    """count how many times we have crossed (-1-ed) a number from p"""
    k=0
    while p[k]==-1 and k<9 :
        """find the first non -1 element in p (it's here that I feel that the code is especially clumsy) """

        k=k+1  
    i=k
    """k is the first element in the cycle """
    print(l[i])
    p[k]=-1
    z=z+1
    j=1
    while l[i]!=k:
        """go from i to l[i] until we get back to k, closing the cycle """
        p[l[i]]=-1
        z=z+1
        i=l[i]
        j+=1
        """g is just used to find the lcm """

        print(l[i])
    prod=lcm(prod,j)
    print('------')   
print(prod)
```

Comment: Could you post the code before minification?

Comment: By "doing this" you mean [computing the permutation order using its cycle decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657461/order-of-a-permutation-using-its-cycle-decomposition), right?

Comment: @le_m yes, I haven't minified the code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/begriffs/2211881 this is a much faster algorithm

Answer (score 7):

## Use the built in `gcd`

In Python 3, you can just do:

```
from math import gcd
```

## Consider keeping with the standard library

Instead of using `np.random.permutation`, consider just using `random.shuffle` to generate a random permutation. Removes the `numpy` dependency altogether.

## Just use `#` instead of `"""`

Comments such as:

```
"""count how many times we have crossed (-1-ed) a number from p"""
```

Are usually used for docstrings, you are using them to elaborate on certain steps in an algorithm, I would use `#` for this.

## Place the cycle decomposition into a function

The while loop introduces a lot of global variables and makes it hard to use, I would put the contents into a function. Also explain that this function displays a permutation as disjoint cycles.

## Please use better names.

I'm still not sure what every variable does. Like why is `p=list(range(10))`? I would think `p` is short for `permutation`, but `l` seems to be what the actual permutation is. This program is really hard to understand simply because of your name choice.

Answer (score 5):

There's room for improvement. Apart from what [@Dair](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161715/61966) already suggested, I'd also recommend a few other changes.

#### Magic numbers

You're using `10` in many places, so why not defining it at the top of your program? (keep in mind that constants should be upper-cased)

---

#### Code style

This:

```
z = z + 1
```

Can be replaced by this:

```
z += 1
```

---

Since you're generating a shuffled list already, why not sort that to get the `p` ? So:

```
p = list(range(10))
```

Can become:

```
p = sorted(l)
```

---

While I understand the reason @Dair suggested `shuffle` instead of `numpy`, I'd suggest you keep it the way you did, as it's the fastest way you can get a shuffled list.

Comment: One thing I would like to note: When I say "consider" I usually mean that there are reasons to disregard the advice I gave but you should, well, consider my point and decide whether it is right for situation. (This is regarding your last point and numpy)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Dair said (especially about variable names):

- You have a lot of hardcoded numbers in there (going from `10` to some other upper limit means replacing quite a few other numbers). Better keeping those in a constant like `UPPER_LIMIT = 10` and using that.
- You don't need that `while p[k]==-1 and k<9 :` loop. You know which element is the first `-1` because you're the one setting it, just keep track of the index and you're good to go (BTW, what if you had a million elements, would you go through all of them every time?).

I didn't test it thoroughly, but this should give you the same result without that loop:

```
k = 0
while z < 10:
    i = k
    print(l[i])
    p[k] = -1
    z = z+1
    j = 1
    old_k = k
    k_set = False
    while l[i] != old_k:
        p[l[i]] = -1
        k += 1
        z += 1
        i = l[i]
        j += 1
        print(l[i])
    prod = lcm(prod,j)
    print('------')

print(prod)
```

Comment: thanks, but you are wrong in the second point (the first element, after the one that is set to -1 at the end of the inner while loop, may be a -1 already)

Comment: I see. In that case you should still consider what I said: keep track of the minimum index of the element that is not `-1`. As I said, you're the one setting it, so you can do that.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, consider a permutation where by my method we -1 out the following elements during the first cycle: 0,8,7,6,5,4 , so the minimal element that is not -1is 1, then after we cross out 2 and 3 how do we know if 9 is still there? I don't know if my approach would run faster if we did it with a set instead of 1-ing in a list like here: https://gist.github.com/begriffs/2211881